# I am having trouble generating a URL to a route

Tags: laravel

I am totally new in laravel. So basically i was trying to make route of a page.But it is showing `http://127.0.0.1:8000/%7B%7Broute('tournament')%7D%7D` this.

```
<li class="effects"> 
    <a href="{{route('tournament')}}"><i class='bx bx-football'></i><span class="modules">Tournament</span></a>
</li>
```

web.php:-

```
Route::get('tournament',[TournamentController::class,'tournament'])->name('tournament');
```

TournamentController:-

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class TournamentController extends Controller
{
    public function tournament()
    {
        return view('admin.pages.tournament');
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO ... please do not put up images of code, code is text and belongs in the question in a codeblock ... on a side note your view doesn't seem to be a blade file

Comment: what is the name of your view file? does it end in `.blade.php`?

Comment: Thank you so much.The problem is solved and yes ,you've said it right.I forgot to name it as .blade.php and for the last three hours i was trying to figure out what's the problem inside the code.Again, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your blade file has `.blade` extension before `.php`

Like below

```
home.blade.php
```